# step/stp file distance between two further point

Tags: java, c#, cad, step

I have a `stp` file. I would like to extract Length, width, depth, number of plies, number of holes and thickness, and being able to calculate the distance between the two further points (to make a box to put the model inside).

I tried `IxMilia` for C# but, it's just a mapping, there is no method to do something with.

I'm currently trying `JSDAI`, but I don't know if this API is able to make some treatment on the data.

If I understand well, the data in a `stp` file (ISO 10303-21) is not enough complete to do a real treat on it.

I'm a little bit lost about what to do with this file to extract what I need.